# Can anyone suggest excellent article of working of HEADERS,COOKIES & SESSIONS besides PHP manual?

Tags: php

I need excellent article of working of HEADERS,COOKIES & SESSIONS besides PHP manual.

Comment: Well, PHP manual is IMHO the best way to learn about it. Anyway, you get any troubles ?

Comment: Most PHP books are highly out of date, written by people of questionable competence (and/or intelligence), or are just trivially rephrased versions of the online PHP manual. The PHP manual is your best bet.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The PHP manual elaborates on all three topics. Do you know how the core concepts of HTTP Headers and Cookies work? Because the PHP provides merely some functions to make use of those. In fact, sessions are built mainly upon cookies.

Comment: Is there something particular you want to know about these topics? Because otherwise, did you already read Wikipedia?

Comment: I actually want to know the working , interaction between them. eg: interaction between headers & cookies.

Comment: @Angelin The book is: http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Definitive-Guide-David-Gourley/dp/1565925092 (there are some others, but this seemed the greatest about the details to me when I was into the topic :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Check out some **links** here

http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/

http://www.developertutorials.com/php-manual/

http://ific.uv.es/informatica/manuales/php/

[pdf format](http://www.axis.com/techsup/cam_servers/dev/files/php3_manual.pdf)

[download](http://www.stars21.com/freemorn//dicts/php_manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some Java, here is a resource that discusses HTTP request-response cycle, Headers, Cookies and Sessions nicely:
http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Hilights:

- Handling the Client Request: HTTP Request Headers
- Generating the Server Response: HTTP Status Codes
- Handling Cookies
- Session Tracking

Comment: yes sure I will.At the end of the day both http concepts not jsp/php.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php to be a useful resource with good coding examples.